# The smallest positive integer of $B$ such that $x,y$ and $z$ are all integers

Tags: linear-algebra

This question relates to a larger problem (on linear algebra) that needs solving.

I have $x =\frac{4B}{23}, y =\frac{ 9B}{23}, z = \frac{7B}{23}$.

I have figured that $B = 23$ is the smallest positive integer for $x,y$ and $z$  to also be integers. I have come to this conclusion by substituting $B$ with a range of integers. Is there a shorter more acceptable way (equation perhaps?) way how to determine this? Another way of asking this could be is it coincidence that the answer is the same as the denominator of the fractions?

Comment: 23 and 4 have no factors in common.  So 23 must divide entirely into B.  23 is the smallest multiple of 23.  So if B =23 works for the others it's the smallest such number.  If it doesn't work for the others it will have to be a higher multiple of 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $aB/c, dB/e, fB/g$ must be integers, the smallest vallue for $B$ is $\text {least common multiple}(\frac {c}{\text {greatest common divosor}(c,a)},\frac d {\gcd (e,d)},\frac f {\gcd (g,f)}) $.